# ChartJS horizontal bar with numbers on both scales

Tags: chart.js

I have an issue with Chartjs bar chart. It doesn't display numeric values on both axis.

I hope you can give an advice how to resolve the issue.

I have the following data structures when both scaled are numeric:

```
{"x": 86, "y": 20},
{"x": 255, "y": 21},
{"x": 207, "y": 34},
```

The y axis is not a category but a number.

Here's how my chart looks like:
[image]

As you can see, there are no values on y axis. Y axis is not even show and the chart looks more like a stacked chart.

Here's how configuration looks like:

```
config: {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          datasets: [],
        },
        plugins: [],
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          indexAxis: "y",
          elements: {
            bar: {
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
          },
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            position: "left",
            ticks: {
              color: "blue",
              font: 24,
            },
          },
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because chart.js still thinks it needs to be a category scale so you will need to override that. If you do that it shows up fine.

A second thing, to make the ticks bigger you need to specify the size in the font object, the font does not accept a number. For all font properties you can specify there you can read the docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/fonts.html)

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
          "x": 86,
          "y": 20
        },
        {
          "x": 255,
          "y": 21
        },
        {
          "x": 207,
          "y": 34
        }
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: "y",
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          color: "blue",
          font: {
            size: 24
          },
        },
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```